# A tool to paste text and make it nicely readable?

Tags: clipboard, reading

I'm looking for a tool that allows me to paste text and transforms this text into a nicely readable format (cf. Pocket, Readily).

**Requirements (can be one of the following):**

- Chrome app/extension
- Linux app
- Online service

**Example workflow:**

1. Copy text from an email conversation
2. Paste this text into the tool
3. Be able to read it as a nicely transformed text